# Efficient Implementation of Priority Queue with Constant-Time Extraction of the Minimum Element

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity, priority-queue, heap

I am working on a project that requires a priority queue with the following characteristics:
Constant-Time Extraction: I need to efficiently extract the minimum element from the priority queue in constant time.

Additional Operations: The priority queue should support standard operations like insertion and decrease-key efficiently as well.
I have considered using a binary heap, but the extraction time for the minimum element is logarithmic. My goal is to achieve constant time for this operation

I attempted to implement a standard binary heap for the priority queue. While the insertion and decrease-key operations are efficient, the logarithmic time complexity for extracting the minimum element doesn't meet my performance requirements.

Comment: As a mathematician friend once said to me many years ago, "Log n is essentially a constant, even for not very large n." Why do you think that the log n extraction time is what's detrimental to your project? Have you profiled and found that to be a bottleneck?

Comment: @pjs it's a somewhat large constant, even for not very large n.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Not really. When compared to linear growth, log(n)/n → 0 quite rapidly.

Comment: Not a refutation. Any somewhat large constant looks similar when compared to linear growth.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Exactly. But that kind of makes my point, since big-O notation isn't the least bit bothered by the magnitude of a constant.

Comment: And yet, in real life, and order of magnitude can often be a big deal.  That's why it's perfectly reasonable to want O(n) instead of O(n log n).

Comment: There is no known priority queue data structure that has O(1) extraction of the minimum element and also has efficient insertion and decrease-key operations. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)#Comparison_of_theoretic_bounds_for_variants. A reverse-sorted list has O(1) removal, but O(n) insertion. Have you actually benchmarked a binary heap to confirm that it's too slow?